# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException PUT

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5

I am trying to update a user, but when I hit the submit button, Laravel  throws the below error:

> "RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206".

I think that the `PUT` method is not allowed, but I do not understand the reason. The request never reaches `UserController@update`.

I have configured a resource route like this:

```
Route::resource('backend/users', 'Backend\UsersController');
```

The output of php artisan `route:list` is:

[image: output of php artisan route:list]

Comment: What does line 206 of RouteCollection.php say?

Comment: Pleaase show us your code view (form) and routes. And this is answer to your question https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/methodnotallowedhttpexception

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem like this: it must be the form's post action error;

`<form method="POST" action="10.241.229.1/backend/users/{{$user->id}}"; accept-charset="UTF-8">`

add the id you want update to the action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use put method like this within form,for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Comment: Hi, thx I already have enabled the hidden method  <form method="POST" action="http://10.241.229.1/backend/users" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">

Comment: If you have already done that's great.If my code is work then make this answer as accepted,that will helpful for others.

Comment: sorry to say but {{ method_field('PUT') }} does not solve the issue method not allowed. I have already configured the hidden method  with  Form::model($user,['method' => $user->exists ? 'put' : 'post']  I am still  at the same point.

Comment: @simonvolk didn't you check the url of laravel official documentation which i provided?

Answer (score 0):

Coming a bit late on this question.

In my experience this kind of error comes for two reasons:

1. as [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing) say, HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form.
2. if you are making the request from a HTML form, and you have the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware enable, than you will need to add a hidden `_token` field to the form with `{{ csrf_token() }}` as value.