# Laravel Route with two parameters

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

I'm trying to see why i'm getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException error with put when its working fine with post method

```
Route::resource('record/{id}/details', 'RecordDetailController');
```

this works:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/records/' . $record->id . '/details/', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

while this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/records/' . $record->id . '/details/', 'method' => 'put')) }}
```

is getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: run php artisan route:list to view all the routes

Comment: i tried running and i could see it  PUT|PATCH | records/{id}/details/{details}      | records.{id}.details.update  | App\Http\Controllers\RecordDetailController@update

Comment: @derping, but that's not the route you're calling. You're not setting a value for `{details}`.

Comment: i think it'll be automatic since i used Route::resource

Comment: No, that's not the route you're building for your form action URL.

Comment: @fubar i've tried  {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('records.{id}.details.update',$record->id, $record_detail->id ))) }} and it also won't work. its kind of weird because post method does work fine but put is getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: use 
`{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST'))}}`

and include this line inside the form: 
`{{method_field('PUT')}}`

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help, i found the answer from this [Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431617/laravel-5-methodnotallowedhttpexception-put)

just put

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```